# Which attacks in Smite do physical damage and which do magical?

Tags: smite

Some gods in Smite are tagged as being physical or magical but somebody told me that all basic attacks are physical (could be wrong). How do I find out what some specific attack I am using is so that I can buy the right items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** This answer is no longer correct, but it's here for historical reasons. Apparently now Mages do Magical damage with their auto attacks as well. See this answer: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/126776/1721.

All basic attacks do physical damage. That's what balances Physical and Magical gods. Magical damage gods do a lot of damage with their skills, but their basic attacks are weak. Physical damage gods have strong basic attacks, but weaker skills. (Some of them have strong skills, but those ones have melee autoattacks so they're not overpowered.)

You can tell what type of damage a skill does by looking at its description.

[image]

There are two things you have to look at, what type of damage an ability does and what stat it scales with. In the above picture you can see the line `Damage: Magical`. That means that ability does Magical Damage, which in-turn means an enemies protection against this skill would depend on their Magical Protection stat.

Then look at the `Damage per hit` line. The numbers in green are the base amount of damage that skill does at each level of its evolution, in this picture, the skill does 100 base damage per hit when it is level 1, and 180 base damage per hit when it is level 5. Then look in the parenthesis next to it and it will tell you that that ability does an addition amount of damage per hit that is equal to 70% of your Magical Power.

The second line, the one in the parenthesis tells you what stat that ability scales with, so if you want that ability to be strong, you have to increase the correct stat.

Comment: At the time of writing this was probably true, however some gods now have magical damage for auto attacks. With the Isis patch she became the first. With the Tyr patch the following gods now deal magical damage with basic attacks as well:
Ares, Bacchus, Freya, Guan Yu, Hades, Sobek, Vulcan, Ymir

Comment: Due to recent updates. This answer is no longer correct. All mages now deal Magical damage on their basic attacks as well.

Comment: @Rapitor A good way to get a new answer is to offer a bounty!

Comment: Stop downvoting me, when I wrote this it was correct and I've updated my answer to reflect that it is outdated and I no longer know what the exact answer is. Stop downvoting me.

Comment: @MarkKramer You should really put the edit right at the top of your answer so it's the first thing people see, and reference the other answer. Most people don't scroll to the bottom to see edits.

Answer (score 5):

Not all basic attacks deal physical damage anymore. The damage of basic attacks of most mages and magical tanks are doing magic damage now! example: Zeus, Ymir, Guyn Yu, Anubis and even Freja now.

The basic attacks that do magical damage are doing 30+25% of the god magical power.
I'm not totally sure abut this number, but for some gods it´s written down in the patch notes for July 24th: [http://www.hirezstudios.com/smitegame/home/latest-news/view/smite-blog/2013/07/24/chang'e-dances-into-smite-brings-jade-rabbit-with-her-](http://www.hirezstudios.com/smitegame/home/latest-news/view/smite-blog/2013/07/24/chang%27e-dances-into-smite-brings-jade-rabbit-with-her-).  I think that counts for all magical basic attacks.

By the way, if you want to see if a god deals magic damage with his basic attacks, you just have to look at the stats on the hompage or in-game, and if their base attack damage is 0+0 per level, you know the god will deal 30+25% of magic power with auto hits.

Comment: According to wiki most mage basic attacks scale with 20% magical power. Ex. [Anubis](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Anubis)